# There seems to be a css transition delay that shouldn't be there

Tags: html, css

Hover over each ribbon and the svg will change colour. All seems good :)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEILH

But, only the first ribbon gives the right result, the others seem to have a delay before the colour transition occurs and the ONLY difference between them are the values of href.

Why is this???

This seems only to be a problem on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the transition from grey to white? Which version of IE are you using?

Try changing the .ico svg selector to: (delete the additional transition-duration, or set it to 0s)

```
 .ico svg {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0s; 
    fill:inherit;
 }
```

I think it might have something to do with your other browsers not understanding transition-duration. But Chrome does, so it adds an additional 0.3s resulting in the delay.